# Zsh shell alias

Tags: macos, zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm using Zsh on Mac OS Terminal as my default shell and using .zshrc file for updating the aliasing

One of the command I am trying to update is `cat`. I want to print the output of the command with syntax highlighting and row number.
So when I type `cat <filename>` it should be aliased to `pygmentize -g <filename> | nl -b a`

Different methods I've tried so far,
Method #1:
`alias cat="pygmentize -g $1 | nl -b a"`

This is printing the file content with row numbers right away but not returning for a while. So when I pressed Ctrl+C I've got below error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pygmentize", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('Pygments==2.7.3', 'console_scripts', 'pygmentize')())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pygments/2.7.3/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygments/cmdline.py", line 557, in main
    return main_inner(popts, args, usage)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pygments/2.7.3/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygments/cmdline.py", line 408, in main_inner
    code = sys.stdin.buffer.read()  # use .buffer to get a binary stream
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Method #2:
`function cat() { pygmentize -g $1 | nl -b a }`

Same output and when pressed Ctrl+C same stack trace like above.

Could someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: I wouldn't shadow the name of a standard utility with a command that does something quite different.

Comment: The error just means `pygmatize` wasn't written to exit cleanly in response to an interrupt signal; you can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, yeah I can ignore the error, but the file content is also not getting printed.

Comment: How exactly are you using the function? The fact that `pygmatize` is trying to read from standard input at all is odd. The alias is definitely wrong, as aliases don't take arguments, but I would expect the function to work correctly with, e.g.,  `cat myfile.py`.

Comment: @BaranidharanS : Would manually invoking `pygmentize -g filename | nl -b a` work?

Comment: @user1934428, yes manually invoking the command is working just fine.

Comment: @chepner, I triggered using `cat myfile.py`

Comment: @BaranidharanS : In this case, your function definition will work as well. Show a reproducible case (which we can copy and paste) which demonstrates that it does not work. We need the exact definition of the function, the way you invoke it, and the error message, if any. Don't fiddle around with Control-C for this test.

Comment: When keeping the below function that @maxxfrazer suggested and sourcing the zshrc it is taking more than 5 mins. <br/>

```
217 ➜ [01/05/21  9:13PM] ~ $ source ~/.zshrc
/Users/sbaranidharan/.zshrc:74: defining function based on alias `cat'
/Users/sbaranidharan/.zshrc:74: parse error near `()'
218 ➜ [01/05/21  9:19PM] ~ $
```
And when I remove that function and source it is running in milliseconds<br/>
```
219 ➜ [01/05/21  9:23PM] ~ $ source ~/.zshrc
219 ➜ [01/05/21  9:23PM] ~ $
```

Comment: And interestingly the process is consuming more than a GB in memory for processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the "function" keyword and it should work fine:

```
cat() {
    pygmentize -g $1 | nl -b a
}
```

If you want to make it scroll a little nicer:

```
cat() {                      
    pygmentize -g $1 | nl -b a | less -Rai
}
```

I'd also recommend calling it something slightly different like `ccat`, as `cat` can be useful still being easily accessible by any scripts you may run.

Comment: Thanks @maxxfrazer for responding. I've tried this approach but when sourcing the .zshrc file I've got some error.

$ source ~/.zshrc
/Users/sbaranidharan/.zshrc:74: defining function based on alias cat'

/Users/sbaranidharan/.zshrc:74: parse error near ()'
$

Comment: A parse error means that something is syntactically wrong. You will have to fix this first.

Comment: When I remove this function .zshrc is getting sourced successfully. So I thought I was writing the function incorrectly. But not sure whats wrong

Comment: @BaranidharanS You apparently already have declared `cat` as an aliases, before you declare it as a function. That's not allowed in Zsh by default.

Comment: Thanks @maxxfrazer renaming the name to ccat from cat did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The error `KeyboardInterrupt` means that you exited the program. But, if it not responding for a while, you could check `Activity Monitor` to see if it is running/what it is doing.